# Overwrite value and create key while update query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb collection that looks like this:

```
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("60471bd482c0da3c0e70d26f"),
     "owner" : "John",
     "propAvailable" : {
        "val1" : true
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60471bd482c0da3c0e76523f"),
    "owner" : "Matt",
    "propAvailable" : {
    "val1" : {
       "val2" : true  
    }
}
```

I need to run an update query on this collection that will update the value of the 'propAvailable' key such that

```
db.collection('props').update({'owner' : 'John'} , {$set : {'propAvailable.val1.val2' : true}});
```

This query works if the document already looks like the second one but gives the error:
**Cannot create field 'val2' in element {'val1': true}** if the document format is the first one. Is there a way to write this query so that it overwrites the boolean 'true' and replaces it with the object `{'val2' : true}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
db.collection.update({
  "owner": "John"
},
{
  $set: {
    "propAvailable.val1": {
      val2: true
    }
  }
})
```

To create `val2: true` inside `propAvailable.val1` and replace its current content.

As you can see working on the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/G3Sqs_iz6TV)

Comment: I do not recommend using this, if `val1` is an object and has additional fields, this approach will overwrite them. https://mongoplayground.net/p/xQtcbPy3-fS

Comment: This is what the OP specifically asked for....

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Mongo version 4.2+ you can use pipelined updates to achieve this, like so:

```
db.collection.updateMany({
  owner: "John"
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "propAvailable.val1": {
        $mergeObjects: [
          {
            $cond: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "object",
                  {
                    $type: "$propAvailable.val1"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "$propAvailable.val1",
              {}
            ]
          },
          {
            val2: true
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GwiAdLzQikR)

For older mongo versions this is impossible to do in 1 query if objects potentially have additional fields under `val1` you want to preserve. You will have to either read and update, or execute two different updates for each case.